# Is there any way to have different Google Tag Manager ID for different URL in Single Page Application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to add multiple Google Tag Manager (GTM) into my Reactjs website. Based on what I've read on Google developer guide, the only way to achieve this is to add 2 `<script>` tag containing javascript snippet provided by Google into the `<head>` tag of index.html file which point to 2 different GTM Ids. This will make my website to always point to 2 GTM Id at the same time but it's not what I expected.

Assuming there is URL1 and URL2, when user switching to URL1, I want the GTM Id to have value GTM-1 and when user go to URL2, GTM Id will be GTM-2. Since Reactjs is SPA, app root get render 1 time and GTM snippet also get excuted at that moment. How do I change the GTM-Id while changing URL (navigating through my website)?

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use `window.location.href` to get the URL of the page.
You can then use an IF statement to output the relevant GTM i.e.:

```
    if (window.location.href = "URL1") {
    /* GTM-1 code */
    }
    else if (window.location.href = "URL2") {
    /* GTM-2 code */
    }
    else { /*Handle error */ }
```

Caveat: This WONT work if you first redirect at server level, and will only function if you have 2 distinct URL's as the 'destination' for a user's visit.